# How to target property id in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

So i have a list of customers with name and id in a button and i will like to delete each customers by obviously targeting the id.

```
<?php

foreach ($customers as $customer)
{
    echo '<button id="btn" onclick="showDelete('.$customer['id'].')">'.$customer['name'].'</button>
    <button id="btn-delete" value="'.$customer['id'].'" style="display:none;">Delete</button>
    ';
}

<script>
function showDelete(id)
{
    let deleteId = id
  let btn = document.getElementById("btn-delete")
  let deleteValue = btn.value
  console.log(deleteValue)
  if ( deleteId === deleteValue ){
      document.getElementById("btn-delete").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Any time i trigger the button only the first `value` of the `delete` button shows

How do i target each name and delete them using vanilla javascript??

Comment: Ids are supposed to be unique within the document. Don't use ids at all, see how to [delegate events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply slightly amend your code to include the id if you really wish to use the id approach

Assumption : the id (in this case is $customer['id']) is `unique` (which is normally the case say if the id is the key), and if this is not the case, then create a unique id by say incrementing a variable such as $index inside the loop.

So the code is

```
<?php

foreach ($customers as $customer)
{
    echo '<button id="btn'. $customer['id'] . '" onclick="showDelete('.$customer['id'].')">'.$customer['name'].'</button>
    <button id="btn-delete' . $customer['id'] . '" value="'.$customer['id'].'" style="display:none;">Delete</button>
    ';
}

<script>
function showDelete(id)
{
    let deleteId = id
  let btn = document.getElementById("btn-delete" + id)
  let deleteValue = btn.value
  console.log(deleteValue)
  if ( deleteId === deleteValue ){
      document.getElementById("btn-delete"+id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP code, the `$customer['id']` is appended to the `id` string and also added as a `value` property. In the JavaScript code, the comparison between `deleteId` and `deleteValue` is unnecessary because they have been set as the same value.

```
function showDelete(id) {
  document.getElementById("btn-delete"+id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

1. php:

```php
<?php $customers = (object) [
    ['name' => 'foo', 'id' => 1],
    ['name' => 'bar', 'id' => 2],
    ['name' => 'baz', 'id' => 3],
]; ?>
<?php foreach ($customers as $customer) : ?>
    <button id="_<?= $customer['id'] ?>" onclick="showDelete(_<?= $customer['id'] ?>)"><?= $customer['name'] ?></button>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

2. JavaScript

```html
<script>
    function showDelete(el) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
</script>
```